# How to create a matrix format in perl

Tags: perl

I have an array of array  in which each array is like:

```
clusterA gene1 1
clusterA gene2 0
clusterB gene1 1
clusterB gene2 0
```

I want to produce a file like:

```
name       gene1    gene2 
clusterA    1         0
clusterB    1         0
```

Current attempt:

```
if (condition) {

    @array = ($cluster, $genes, "1");
}
elsif (not condition) {

    @array = ($cluster, $genes, "0");
}
push @AoA, [ @array ];
```

@A0A is my array of array.

Comment: can you clarify the structure of your arrays?

Comment: Please post your attempt

Comment: This looks like a perfect usecase for a CSV with column headers. (unless you want it to look like a matrix, which will need some output formatting). Check DBD::CSV module on CPAN. If you're OK to replace the Tabs/spaces in your matrix with a comma, then DBD::CSV is the way to go. let me know, I will try posting a solution in CSV format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution doesn't know the genes' names ahead of time. It will create columns for all seen genes. And, it uses a hash of hashes. I solved a similiar problem and was able to use some of the same parts of the solution [here](http://perlguru.com/gforum.cgi?post=71491;sb=post_latest_reply;so=ASC;forum_view=forum_view_collapsed;guest=5787217).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = map [split], split /\n/, <<EOF;
clusterA gene1 1
clusterA gene2 0
clusterB gene1 1
clusterB gene2 0
clusterC gene3 9
EOF

my %data;
for my $aref (@array) {
    $data{$aref->[0]}{$aref->[1]} = $aref->[2]; 
}

my %seen;
my @genes = sort
            grep ! $seen{$_}++,
            map keys %$_, values %data;

my $format = "%-15s" . "%-10s" x @genes . "\n";

printf $format, 'Cluster', @genes;

for my $name (sort keys %data) {
    my $href = $data{$name};
    printf $format, $name, map defined $_ ? $_ : 'none', @$href{ @genes };
}
```

This produced the output below.

```
Cluster        gene1     gene2     gene3
clusterA       1         0         none
clusterB       1         0         none
clusterC       none      none      9
```

**Update:** It would probably be easier to create the hash-of-hashes in the first place instead of the array-of-arrays. Like:

```
my %data;
$data{$cluster}{$genes} = condition ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @AoA = ( ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'] );

open my $outf, ">", "output"
    or die();

print $outf join(" ", qw/name gene1 gene2/), "\n";
foreach my $arr (@AoA) {

    my @data = @{$arr};
    print $outf join(" ", @data), "\n";
}
close $outf;
```

Comment: this is not the answer  ,in this case "b and "e" should be column of matrix and "a" and "d" are rows and "c" and"f" are the values corresponding to row and columns respectively

Answer (score 0):

```perl
my %HoH;

foreach my $row (@AoA)
{
  $HoH{$row->[0]}{$row->[1]} = $row->[2];
}

print <<EOF;
name       gene1    gene2
clusterA    $HoH{clusterA}{gene1}         $HoH{clusterA}{gene2}
clusterB    $HoH{clusterB}{gene1}         $HoH{clusterB}{gene2}
EOF
```

Comment: @fxzuz: I've made it a bit more explicit. Not sure what else I can do except link to [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-HASHES) and [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%3c%3cEOF). There's not much to understand TBH. I'm not providing a "teach yourself Perl" service.

Answer (score 0):

Did shaq want totals? If so the answer will be more like (leaving all file I/O out to simplify test):

```perl
my @AOA = (
  [ qw(clusterA gene1 1) ],
  [ qw(clusterA gene2 0) ],
  [ qw(clusterB gene1 1) ],
  [ qw(clusterB gene2 0) ],
);

my %clusters;
my @genes = ( 0, 0 );

foreach my $array ( @AOA ) {

    my ( $cluster, $gene, $value ) = @$array;
    if ( $gene =~ /^gene(\d+)$/ ) {

        my $v = $1; 
        $clusters{$cluster} = [ 0, 0 ] 
                   unless ( exists $clusters{$cluster} );
        $clusters{$cluster}->[$v-1] += $value;
    }   
}

my $format = '%-12s %6s %6s'."\n";
printf( $format, qw( name gene1 gene2 ) );

foreach my $cluster ( sort keys %clusters ) {

    printf $format, $cluster, @{ $clusters{$cluster} };
}
```